# Achieveing sustained LCR oscillations

Tags: electrical-engineering

Consider a series LCR circuit. Once power source is removed, the electrical energy oscillates for some time before damping out completely. I want a LCR circuit such that 1) it has high resonance frequency , say 1 GHz and 2) it oscillates for some time say 1 min.

Consider following numbers. To achieve 1 GHz, L and C must be very low. Let C=1 pF and L=25nH. This gives us resonance frequency around 1 GHz. At such high frequency the inductor wire will pose some resistance, let us assume R=0.001 Ohm, even though it is likely to be more. The attenuation factor $\alpha=R/2L$ is going to be high, which means the oscillations even if under-damped, will not sustain even for a second. Clearly there is a trade-off between high frequency and longer oscillation.

Is there a way to achieve both? It is ok even it is achieved without removing the power source, however, note that the voltage source is 10-100KV DC.
Just keeping the LCR connected to the power source will not result in oscillations, in my understabnding.

Comment: Inductors  have reactance not resistance.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad inductors have resistance, they are made of conducting wires. also, as frequency of power supply increases so does the resistance of a wire (of inductor).

Comment: that's not the resistance of inductor, that's the resistance of the whole wiring circuit, if i take your value say 0.001 the ratio between this and R would results is a very small resistance that we neglect its effect in circuit THE GOOD CIRCUIT IS INDEPENDENT OF ACTUAL VALUES OF ITS COMPONENTS  , the skin effect comes in to play when where are talking about large scale circuits like transmission lines. Talking about resistance of inductors is nonsense.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad you are missing the point. agreed that wiring will have resistance. but by making smaller in length and thicker in cross section you can reduce its resistance. my point is even if you make resistance of the wirings negligible, you cannot do away with resistance associated with the inductor, which even at very low values prevent me from achieveing the stated objectives.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad get *any* real-world inductor, as used in *any* electronic circuit you like, and put an ohmmeter across it. You are confusing the idealized components used in "AC electrical circuits 101" with the real world. And real world inductors also have self-capacitance - they can resonate all on their own, *without* an LCR circuit. See https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/comms-lab-isr if you don't believe me.

Comment: @alephzero Maybe plumbers or carpenters pick an ohmmeter to measure such a delicate values, but so far i have never ever ever seen, somebody even care about this small values on real board. And since you mentioned a real world application, then i don't see where this circuit has any

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Inductors are made of wire, wire has resistance, inductors have resistance, period. If you may or not dismiss it from equations depends a lot on application, if you've never cared about inductors resistance you do a job different of mine.

Comment: @carloc I'm not denying the existence of such resistance, what i'm saying is an inductor and a capacitor don't make a LRC circuit. The source resistance is way bigger than the whole wire resistance, so it's not a LRC circuit it's LC circuit. Am i wrong ?

Comment: @SamFarjamirad oh okay I must have misunderstood, if external series resistance is much higher than inductor stray one, the latter can obviously be neglected. Ok so far. But then I cannot follow you when you say this series resonating circuit can now be seen as simple LC circuit. This would be the case when total series resistance is much smaller than LC characteristic impedance.

Comment: @carloc yes i stated it so vague sorry, OP means by LRC circuit, a pure LC circuit, but then because of this very small intrinsic resistance of inductor,  OP models it as a LRC circuit so there is no external series resistance, OP uses the same symbol for this resistance as in LRC . I hope i cleared the confusion.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad i need just one clarification. are you saying the resistance of an inductor cannot be in series with LC?

Comment: @efvchu No it is not so, but how much is the resistance of your source ? If it's just one Ohm then, it's thousand times bigger than this intrinsic resistance so you can neglect it and you actually build a LC circuit, if you use a real external resistance say 1k Ohm then the total resistance of this serie circuit is 1k+0.001 Ohm, you can in this case neglect the resistance, why ? because your external resistance is not perfect, so it has a tolerance less than 0.001 and it's nonsense to talk about this intrinsic resistance.

Comment: You can always simulate the circuit in pspice or LTspice, you can download the free software in analog.com